# Eclipse/Maven/Junit : junit throws classnotfound even though the compiled class is in test-classes folder

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, junit4, m2eclipse, m2e

I recently upgraded my environment from Eclipse Ganymede to Eclipse Juno. My application was using the old maven-eclipse-plugin, so I had to make changes in the .classpath and .project and .settings files so that the m2e plugin in eclipse juno gets all the information correctly. I did this by following this link - http://blog.frankel.ch/migrating-from-m2eclipse-to-m2e

My application runs perfectly fine using tomcat7 and maven also works fine.
My issues started when I tried to run a test as junit test in eclipse. This gives me a ClassNotFoundException. As a side note even if I add my test-classes folder as a classpath variable in eclipse, it still has issues because then it says it cannot find the resources folder. This very same environment worked perfectly fine with the earlier eclipse, maven plugin and classpath configuration. So I don't know what has changed.

I am sharing with you my project structure and classpath details. Please bear with me as the question is a bit long.

- XXX

  - DBUnit (similar to Web)
  - Others (similar to Web)
  - Web

    - src/main/java
    - src/main/resources
    - src/test/java
    - src/test/resources
    - target/classes
    - target/test-classes
    - .settings
    - .classpath
    - .project
  - target/classes
  - .settings
  - .classpath
  - .project

The classpath entry under Web is as follows :

```xml
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java"/>
<classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources"/>
<classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
```

And the classpath entry under XXX is as follows :

```xml
<classpathentry kind="src" output="Others/target/classes" path="Others/src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="DBUnit/src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="Web/src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry excluding="mock/" kind="src" output="Web/target/test-classes" path="Web/src/test/java"/>
<classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="Web/target/classes" path="Web/src/main/resources"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="TOMCAT_HOME/lib/annotations-api.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="TOMCAT_HOME/lib/el-api.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="TOMCAT_HOME/lib/jasper.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="TOMCAT_HOME/lib/jsp-api.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="TOMCAT_HOME/lib/servlet-api.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
```

So when I clean the project eclipse does not place the main java classes under the the module1/target/classes folder and it also does not copy the resources folder under classes either.

I have searched around quite a bit regarding this problem.

One solution also suggested to import the project into eclipse as a Maven project and update configuration. This splits my project into multiple modules and maven/eclipse throws me the exception - "Path must include project and resource name". I don't understand this error either.

Another one suggested the removal of excluding="**". I removed it but that did not help either.

Is there something wrong with the project structure? Does module1 require classpath and project files?

Please help, I'll be really grateful. Thanks.

**Update 03rd Dec 2012**

This is the exception -

```
Class not found com.iei.gas.service.QuartzTestService
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.iei.gas.service.QuartzTestService 
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:693)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:429)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Which class doesn't it found?

Comment: Other note: it is discouraged to edit the `.classpath` by hand, it is managed by Maven (it will drop all changes on update). Try project -> right-click -> Maven -> Update project. Let's see if it helps.

Comment: Any junit test case that I try to run from eclipse (run as junit test), although I see them in the test-classes directory. I tried Updating as Maven project that did not help (it did not make any changes to the classpath).

Comment: Pleaes do try dropping (.metadata) and project files (.settings, .classpath and .project) and creating your workspace  from scratch instead of migrating.

Comment: I did that today, but it still does not work. Only if I add all the target folders as classpath variables in eclipse it works. But I should not need to do that right.